Words describe a good person with very malicious thoughts
Looking for a word or words to describe someone who wants to be good and is mostly good but struggles with malicious intent. One with a wish to inflict harm despite a history of, and strong desire to be good, honorable and even virtuous.

Mixed emotions make for real people. Thank God we are judged by our actions and not our imagination.

The formulation of your question, although much sense can be derived from it, is  very poor on account of the disregard it shows for the basic grammatical principles of the English language  (correct sentence, punctuation); I advise you to revise it and come up with something more conform to present day English standards. Putting questions to the ELU does not mean that you can forget to pay attention to how you write.

I might add that one word for this would be an average human being.

Maybe something like "conflicted"?

I think it will depend on the nature of the malicious intent e.g. whether it's pathological or self-interested. If they're always thinking what would be the most advantageous course of action, or always second-guessing their actions, that would be very different from someone hearing voices telling them to kill.
